# Use New Browser Window to Control/Display Elements on Parent Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question regarding a question I received from a customer.  The customer asked me if it is possible to control elements (photos, links and text) from two different windows, in the same browser.  The customer has a project that will need to be displayed on two monitors.  One monitor for display and the other monitor for control.  They want to open a new window from the main interface on monitor A, drag that new window to monitor B (which will contain thumbnails of images and links).  When they click on a thumbnail of a image or links on the window displaying on Monitor B, the large version of the image or the link information with display/appear on the main interface window on monitor A.  The reason why my customer is requesting this, they don’t want the viewer to see them interacting with the elements.  Long story short, Monitor A window will be for show and Monitor B window will be for control.  I hope this make sense to someone and this concept is possible.  I like to create this using javaScript/jQuery/HTML.  Any advice will greatly be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was posted here on Stackoverflow. The answer was posted under this title, "Load img in window.opener from child window using jQuery".  Works perfect!  Thanks to all who reviewed my post and if you need to do the same as I wrote in my original post, the below code will do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkID =$(this).attr("id");         
    var imgSrcVal = $('img', this).attr("src");

    if (location.href.indexOf("/") != 0) {
        var base = location.href.replace(/(.+)(\/)(.*)/, "$1");
        imgSrcVal = base + "/" + imgSrcVal;
    }

    window.opener.document.getElementById("id_1").src = imgSrcVal;
 });
});
```